# Ansible - check if item in a list of dictionaries is present in other list of dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

How to check if an object of a list of dictionaries is present in another list of dictionaries (with Ansible?)

You could try jinja filters `selectattr` - I had an issue with using it, so I did revert to a simplified but ugly solution - build a `filtered list` and compare filtered attributes only (`list-to-list`).
I do not like it, but it works.
Let me know if you know other way.

playbook:

```
- name: find existing system_crontabs  #would generate a list of dict
  find:
    path: /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
  register: system_side_crontabs
  become: True

- name: create lists of system_cron_names and repo_cron_names
  set_fact:
    system_cron_names: "[]"
    repo_cron_names: "[]"

- name: build list of system_cron_names
  set_fact:
    system_cron_names: "{{ system_cron_names }} + [ '{{ item.path |basename }}' ]"
  with_items: "{{ system_side_crontabs.files }}"

- name: build lists of repo_cron_names
  set_fact:
    repo_cron_names: "{{ repo_cron_names }} + [ '{{ item.user }}' ]"
  with_items: "{{ crontabs }}"

- name: assert check if an object of system_crontab is defined in repo_crontab
  assert:
    that: "{{ [item] |intersect(repo_cron_names) | length }} == 1"
  with_items: "{{ system_cron_names }}"
```

hosts_vars/prd-inner-mgmt202  #a list of dictionaries

```
crontabs:
  - user: root
    crontab_rules: |
      11 1 * * * find /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ -atime +10  -delete
```

a result of find

```
ok: [prd-inner-mgmt202] => {
    "changed": false,
    "examined": 1,
    "files": [                         ### List of dictionary
        {

            "path": "/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root",

        },
        {

            "path": "/var/spool/cron/crontabs/another_file",

        }
    ],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "age": null,
            "age_stamp": "mtime",
            "contains": null,
            "file_type": "file",
            "follow": false,
            "get_checksum": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "path": "/var/spool/cron/crontabs/",
            "paths": [
                "/var/spool/cron/crontabs/"
            ],
            "patterns": [
                "*"
            ],
            "recurse": false,
            "size": null,
            "use_regex": false
        },
        "module_name": "find"
    },
    "matched": 1,
    "msg": ""
}
```

generate a list of strings that are easy to compare

```
TASK [mid_crontab : build list of system_cron_names] **************************
   "ansible_facts": {
        "system_cron_names": [
            "root",

        ]
    },
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "system_cron_names": [
                "root"
            ]
        },
        "module_name": "set_fact"
    },
```

generate another list of strings

```
TASK [mid_crontab : build list of repo_cron_names] *****************************

ok: [prd-inner-mgmt202] => (item={u'crontab_rules': u'11 1 * * * find /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ -atime +10  -delete\n', u'user': u'root'}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "repo_cron_names": [
            "root"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "repo_cron_names": [
                "root",
        "other"
            ]
        },
        "module_name": "set_fact"
    },
    "item": {
        "crontab_rules": "11 1 * * * find /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ -atime +10  -delete\n",
        "user": "root"
    }
}
```

Assert the required check, use `intersect` jinja filter. In my case a system defined object (cron record) should exist in my repository - so the list should have 1 element.

```
TASK [mid_crontab : assert check if system_crontab is defined in repo_crontab] *

ok: [prd-inner-mgmt202] => (item=root) => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "that": "1 == 1"
        },
        "module_name": "assert"
    },
    "item": "root",
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to reduce original dict to list of strings (names) and compare the difference:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    crontabs:
      - user: root
        crontab_rules: xxx
  tasks:
    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
      register: myfiles
    - assert:
        that: sys_crons_violation | count == 0
        msg: "This crons are not defined in repo : {{ sys_crons_violation | join(', ') }}"
      vars:
        sys_crons: "{{ myfiles.files | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') | list }}"
        repo_crons: "{{ crontabs | map(attribute='user') | list }}"
        sys_crons_violation: "{{ sys_crons | difference(repo_crons) }}"
```

result:

```
TASK [find] ************************

TASK [assert] **********************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "sys_crons_violation | count == 0",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "This crons are not defined in repo : another_file"
}
```